# http post with json file and nested array Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, http-post, http-get

I have an app that has the ability to get and post through http with a model of a relational database. I am able to display my data and the JSON data looks like this on http://localhost/**/api/complaint:

```
{
"CHECKLISTs": [{
    "COMP_ID": 1,
    "IntOIMRec": "No"
}],
"COMP_ID": 1,
"FileNum": "case1"
}
```

using angular:

```
<tr data-ng-repeat="complaint in complaints">
<td><strong data-ng-hide="complaint.editMode">{{ complaint.FileNum }}</strong></td>
<td>
<p data-ng-hide="complaint.editMode">{{ complaint.CHECKLISTs[0].IntIAB}}</p>
<input data-ng-show="complaint.editMode" type="text" data-ng-model="customer.Status" />
</tr>
```

I am also able to http post with this controller:

```
//Insert complaint
$scope.add = function () {
    $scope.loading = true;
    $http.post('/api/Complaint/', this.newcomplaint).success(function (data) {
        alert("Added Successfully!!");
        $scope.addMode = false;
        $scope.complaints.push(data);
        $scope.loading = false;
    }).error(function (data) {
        $scope.error = "An Error has occured while Adding complaint! " + data;
        $scope.loading = false;
    });
};
```

But when I add the Checklists[0] to my form to add it, it will not add a new record. My code for the form to add a new record looiks like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <strong class="error">{{ error }}</strong>
        <p data-ng-hide="addMode"><a data-ng-click="toggleAdd()" href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-primary">Add New</a></p>
        <form name="addComplant" data-ng-show="addMode" style="width:600px;margin:0px auto;">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="cid" class="col-sm-2 control-label">ID:</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cid" placeholder="please enter id" data-ng-model="newcomplaint.FileNum" required />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="cname" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name:</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cname" placeholder="please enter your name" data-ng-model="newcomplaint.CHECKLISTs[0].IntIAB" />
                </div>
            </div>

            <br />
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                    <input type="submit" value="Add" data-ng-click="add()" class="btn btn-primary" />
                    <input type="button" value="Cancel" data-ng-click="toggleAdd()" class="btn btn-primary" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <br />
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

my console.log output:

[console.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/raZhp.png)

Can someone tell me if I can display it using angular http.get and http.post, why can't I add into checklists field when it is clearly in the JSON file and it displays just fine? The error i get is [object object] ?

Thank you

Comment: console.log the `data ` from the success handler and add it to the question.

Comment: @JohannesJander I have added it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just by looking at your code, it seems that you're pushing into $scope.complaints, instead of $scope.complaint.CHECKLISTs

Do you have an ng-repeat somewhere?

Comment: I do, i have added it into my html code under use angular. I though that $scope.complaints already has checklists in the json file?

Answer (score 0):

Change `$scope.complaints.push(data);` to `$scope.newcomplaint = data`. Or if complaints really should be an array, then you need an `ng-repeat` on your form

Comment: Hi Johannes, I do have a ng-repeat on my page but not inside of the add new complaint form. I also changed the $scope.complaints.push(data); to $scope.newcomplaint = data which did not fix the error [object Object] but still worked.

Comment: Just console.log the data from the error handler and see what's inside.

Comment: The error in the error handler says :: "Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1[CRAMSMVC.Models.CHECKLIST]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.

Comment: ↵To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List<T>) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.
↵Path 'CHECKLISTs.0', line 1, position 35." What would you suggest? I am still learning and don't want to mess up my code.

Comment: "mess up your code" - that's really not an argument. As a coder, you mess up your code everyday to find a problem and then you tidy it up again. Try `$http.post('/api/Complaint/', [this.newcomplaint]).success(function (data) {` - that error comes from your .NET backend, so I have no idea why it is thrown.

Comment: You are correct. I will continue try to search for a solution with this error. That method did not work.